PersistentVector Error, or 'long' error in a small tic tac toe game
My clojure tic tac toe game won't work and I have lost the thread.... I am not exactly sure which part is broken and I am having trouble figuring out my own code. Could someone help me understand why I am getting this error and if there are any other fundamental problems with this attempt at making tic tac toe?
;An implementation of
;Tic-Tac-Toe
;by [Me]

(ns tic-tac-two.main
  (:require [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]]
            [clojure.string :refer [blank?]]))

(def board-state
  [[" " " " " "]
   [" " " " " "]
   [" " " " " "]])

(defn print-board [board]
  (doseq [row board]
    (println (clojure.string/join " | " (map #(or % " ") row)))))

(defn print-heading []
  (println (str " ======================\n") 
                 "My Tic-Tac-Toe Game\n"
                 "======================\n"))

(defn legal-move? [row col board-state]
  (clojure.string/blank? (get-in board-state [row col])))

(defn check-winner
  "This part of the algorithm reviews the state of the board
   specifically by evaluating the diagonal axis of the board
   and determining whether there are any filled lines in one
   cardinal direction. If so it will return that particular 
   array or nil"
  [board]
  (let [lines (concat board
                      (apply map vector board)
                      [[(get board [0 0]) (get board [1 1]) (get board [2 2])]
                       [(get board [0 2]) (get board [1 1]) (get board [2 0])]])]
    (some (fn [line]
            (when (and (not (every? #(= " " %) line))
                       (every? #(= % (first line)) line))
              (first line)))
          lines)))

(defn make-move
  "Make-move functions by taking appropriate
   symbol ('X' or 'O') into the appropriate
   spot in the state vectors for both the
   player and computer."
  [board row col player]
  (if (blank? (get board [row col]))
    (assoc-in board [row col] player)
    (do
      (println "Invalid move! Spot already taken.")
      board)))
; ex. =>([0 1] [0 2] [1 0] [1 1] [1 2] [2 0] [2 1])

(defn get-available-moves
  "Iterate through the 'open' board positions and
   return a destructured array of available positions
   based on their grid coordinates."
  [board-state]
  (->> (for [row (range (count board-state))
             col (range (count (first board-state)))]
         (when (legal-move? row col board-state)
           [row col]))
       (remove nil?)))

(defn evaluate-board
  "This function applies a score to the potential move
  being evaluated. A score of 0 inevitably continues
  the game and will lead to an updated board state,
  while a 1 or -1 signal the end of the game."
  [board player]
  (cond
    (= (check-winner board) player) 1
    (= (check-winner board) (if (= player "X") "O" "X")) -1
    :else 0))

(defn minimax
  "Minimax is a recursive algorithm that evaluates the
   score and indicating whether the game will progress, 
   or otherwise declaring a winner. Score is updated 
   with each recursive pass."
  [board player depth]
  (if (empty? (get-available-moves board))
    (evaluate-board board player)
    (let [available-moves (get-available-moves board)
          scores-and-moves (for [[row col] available-moves]
                             (let [new-board (make-move board row col player)
                                   score (minimax new-board (if (= player "X") "O" "X") (dec depth))]
                               [score [row col]]))]
      (if (= player "X")
        (apply max-key first scores-and-moves)
        (apply min-key first scores-and-moves)))))

(defn valid-input? [input]
  (and (not (blank? input)) (some #(= (Integer/parseInt input) %) [0 1 2])))

(defn get-valid-input
  "This function ensures that the user can only enter an integer [0 1 2]"
  [prompt valid-fn]
  (loop []
    (println prompt)
    (let [input (read-line)]
      (if (valid-fn input)
        (Integer/parseInt input)
        (do
          (println "Invalid input. Please try again.")
          (recur))))))

(defn -main
  "This is the main game loop. It first prints a heading
   and then takes user input. It will print an updated board
   each turn and continue until one of the players have one;
   correctly identifying the winner, declaring them the winner,
   and then gracefully exiting."
  []
  (let [_ (do
            (print-heading)
            (println "  Enter your REAL name"))
        player-name (read-line)
        _ (println (str "Okay " player-name ", welcome to the game!"))]
    (loop [current-board board-state] 
      (let [_ (print-board current-board)
            winner (check-winner current-board)
            winner-name (if (= winner "X") player-name
                            "Computer...")]
        (if winner
          (println (str "Player " winner-name " wins!"))
          (let [row (get-valid-input "Enter your row [0, 1, 2]:" #(valid-input? %))
                col (get-valid-input "Enter your column [0, 1, 2]:" #(valid-input? %))
                board-after-player-move (make-move current-board row col "X")
                [ai-score [ai-row ai-col]] (minimax board-after-player-move "O" 9)
                board-after-computer-move (make-move board-after-player-move ai-row ai-col "O")]
            (recur board-after-computer-move)))))))

Can you help me understand why I am getting this persistent vector error and let me know if there are fundamental issues with my approach and code style?
; Execution error (ClassCastException) at tic-tac-two.main/minimax (REPL:98).
; class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Number is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
Using *e in the repl returns
*e
#error {:cause "class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Number is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"
        :via
        [{:type java.lang.ClassCastException
          :message "class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.Number is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')"
          :at [clojure.lang.Numbers lt "Numbers.java" 253]}]
        :trace
        [[clojure.lang.Numbers lt "Numbers.java" 253]
         [clojure.core$min_key invokeStatic "core.clj" 5069]
         [clojure.core$min_key invoke "core.clj" 5062]
         [clojure.lang.AFn applyToHelper "AFn.java" 160]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 135]
         [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
         [clojure.core$apply invoke "core.clj" 662]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 96]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 80]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184$fn__11185 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 92]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 90]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq force "LazySeq.java" 50]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq realize "LazySeq.java" 89]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 106]
         [clojure.lang.Cons next "Cons.java" 41]
         [clojure.lang.RT boundedLength "RT.java" 1810]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 133]
         [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
         [clojure.core$apply invoke "core.clj" 662]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 95]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 80]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184$fn__11185 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 92]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 90]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq force "LazySeq.java" 50]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq realize "LazySeq.java" 89]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 106]
         [clojure.lang.Cons next "Cons.java" 41]
         [clojure.lang.RT boundedLength "RT.java" 1810]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 133]
         [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
         [clojure.core$apply invoke "core.clj" 662]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 96]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 80]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184$fn__11185 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 92]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 90]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq force "LazySeq.java" 50]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq realize "LazySeq.java" 89]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 106]
         [clojure.lang.Cons next "Cons.java" 41]
         [clojure.lang.RT boundedLength "RT.java" 1810]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 133]
         [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
         [clojure.core$apply invoke "core.clj" 662]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 95]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 80]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184$fn__11185 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 92]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 90]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq force "LazySeq.java" 50]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq realize "LazySeq.java" 89]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 106]
         [clojure.lang.Cons next "Cons.java" 41]
         [clojure.lang.RT boundedLength "RT.java" 1810]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 133]
         [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
         [clojure.core$apply invoke "core.clj" 662]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 96]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 80]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184$fn__11185 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 92]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 90]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq force "LazySeq.java" 50]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq realize "LazySeq.java" 89]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 106]
         [clojure.lang.Cons next "Cons.java" 41]
         [clojure.lang.RT boundedLength "RT.java" 1810]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 133]
         [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
         [clojure.core$apply invoke "core.clj" 662]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 95]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 80]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184$fn__11185 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 92]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax$iter__11179__11183$fn__11184 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 90]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq force "LazySeq.java" 50]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq realize "LazySeq.java" 89]
         [clojure.lang.LazySeq seq "LazySeq.java" 106]
         [clojure.lang.Cons next "Cons.java" 41]
         [clojure.lang.RT boundedLength "RT.java" 1810]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn applyTo "RestFn.java" 133]
         [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 669]
         [clojure.core$apply invoke "core.clj" 662]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 96]
         [tic_tac_two.main$minimax invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 80]
         [tic_tac_two.main$_main invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 135]
         [tic_tac_two.main$_main invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 113]
         [tic_tac_two.main$eval11215 invokeStatic "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 1]
         [tic_tac_two.main$eval11215 invoke "NO_SOURCE_FILE" 1]
         [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7700]
         [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 7655]
         [clojure.core$eval invokeStatic "core.clj" 3232]
         [clojure.core$eval invoke "core.clj" 3228]
         [nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__1357$fn__1358 invoke "interruptible_eval.clj" 87]
         [clojure.lang.AFn applyToHelper "AFn.java" 152]
         [clojure.lang.AFn applyTo "AFn.java" 144]
         [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 667]
         [clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_ invokeStatic "core.clj" 1990]
         [clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_ doInvoke "core.clj" 1990]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 428]
         [nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__1357 invoke "interruptible_eval.clj" 87]
         [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9244$fn__9247 invoke "main.clj" 437]
         [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9244 invoke "main.clj" 437]
         [clojure.main$repl$fn__9253 invoke "main.clj" 459]
         [clojure.main$repl invokeStatic "main.clj" 459]
         [clojure.main$repl doInvoke "main.clj" 368]
         [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 1526]
         [nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate invokeStatic "interruptible_eval.clj" 84]
         [nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate invoke "interruptible_eval.clj" 56]
         [nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__1390$fn__1394 invoke "interruptible_eval.clj" 152]
         [clojure.lang.AFn run "AFn.java" 22]
         [nrepl.middleware.session$session_exec$main_loop__1460$fn__1464 invoke "session.clj" 218]
         [nrepl.middleware.session$session_exec$main_loop__1460 invoke "session.clj" 217]
         [clojure.lang.AFn run "AFn.java" 22]
         [java.lang.Thread run "Thread.java" 1583]]}```


Whenever you seen an exception in a REPL, evaluate *e to see its full stacktrace. It'll help you figure out where the error originates from.

I did that and am trying to use the stack trace that I edited into the post. Thank you for that knowledge.

The topmost entry in the stacktrace that mentions your code is about tic_tac_two.main$minimax. That $ sign in there is due to how Clojure code is translated into JVM bytecode - you can replace it mentally with /. Same for _ - replace it with -. This gives us tic-tac-two.main/minimax, that points right to the problematic function.
Moving up the stacktrace, the closest entry mentioning a function that your minimax function actually uses is clojure.core$min_key - that corresponds to clojure.core/min-key.
From the docstring of that function:

Returns the x for which (k x), a number, is least.

So it expects for the key function to return a number for every enty in the collection. But the scores-and-moves collection is a lazy seq created with for that contains only vectors. Hence the error that basically says that you cannot treat a vector as a number.
Assuming you wanted to find the lowest (and the highest, in the case of max-key) entry based on the score, try replacing the call to first with ffirst.

Thank you for your detailed response -
That makes reading the stacktrace a bit more understandable... I will keep that in mind.
I tried ffirst and it is producing the same error right now.

It seems that the minimax function is supposed to return both the score and the coordinates. But it also uses itself recursively, expecting to receive only the score. However, when the board it empty, minimax does return just a single number.

So, you have to thoroughly debug minimax with whatever debugging technique you prefer and make it return exactly what you expect - preferably without it returning different data shapes under different conditions.
